# HTTP Request Using Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, httprequest

I am trying to crawl a website using NodeJS. I am making an HTTP request using Axios. I am able to only fetch those items which are available when webpage is loaded. All the HTML which is loaded when I scroll down further is not fetched.

Here is my code.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

// table view
const url = "https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table";

fetchData(url).then((res) => {
    const html = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const unilist = $('.TableTabular__TableContainer-febmbj-0.guaRKP > tbody > tr >td ');

    unilist.each(function() {

        let title = $(this).find('div').attr("name");

        if (typeof(title) == 'string') {
            console.log(title);
            } 

    });
})

async function fetchData(url){
    console.log("Crawling data...")

    // make http call to url
    let response = await axios(url).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    if(response.status !== 200){
        console.log("Error occurred while fetching data");
        return;
    }
    return response;

}
```

I am trying to get all the university names. However, I am only able to get 13 universities because the others are loaded only when the page is manually scrolled down.

How do I access all the universities in the webpage: https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table

Comment: Seems like they have a paginated API. So you can basically change the page in the query params of the below URL - https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/api/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_page=10.

You can basically parse the JSON response to get the data for each page.

Comment: Found this by observing what the network activity on website, using dev-tools. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora Thanks a lot for your help. May I ask how do I know what is the total number of pages in the website?

Comment: They seem to be returning 404 if the page doesn't exist. So you would just need to keep reading pages until you get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');

const url = "https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/api/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&_page=7&study=Engineering";

let options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "authority": "www.usnews.com",
        "method": "GET",
        //"path": `/best-colleges/api/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&_page=6&study=Engineering`,
        "scheme": "https",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "cookie": `ak_bmsc=60A136143B076291C93DD9728862F728172B301F314600004917B85E8498E04F~pl5NwmZFHheJnzgnDGIGpBb4YDDOuhPDVqrNGDysdm/dDPzFJis9zP1awrKKsxeJBlvqZWW6E3ssLbAdi/nUkIEkEiVPu1NDDQge8FegXwVN6Ren/u+X8dx6/TRgRIIXtbj2n2ieih1+SzTEccExtz3QgcXFx+ZxSM1O3Xoe5crrhltym4VHVynMHnup+h3TaL9tLmsoWiopb9GlEG1eTlXIoyPsKVt2FA+s1MJP5zVmQ=; akacd_www=2177452799~rv=53~id=9087b102caf120794dbb1eeceaf4ccc8; usn_session_id=891228875906785; usn_visitor_id=8912288759182043; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1589122887855r0.7555247616511707; usprivacy=1YNY; s_cc=true; s_fid=6C0F54971BC55B63-31DB4C74AAF1424B; ntv_as_us_privacy=1YNY; _ga=GA1.2.1252831587.1589122893; _gid=GA1.2.1293277568.1589122893; _fbp=fb.1.1589122894850.768122457; _ntv_uid=a074b9dd-6b5b-4f4b-b257-f9e7ee116412; __gads=ID=3343601cd2e45d2f:T=1589122898:S=ALNI_MZI2Mh_V-ROYbHt3s2k1h83if7i8A; edu-page-views=2; modal-page-views=2; pageview-count-Best Colleges Q2 2020 Audience Survey=2; CUID=N,1589123026657:ALHGLuQAAAAPTiwxNTg5MTIzMDI2NjU3xMc3klevipXW6CRMhCp96C/0wAIB5hXG0/fOK/1Ol60Pak5Dv6v1GHuSJcnhwzLp/ZPAF0+w1p4ic6ZfQHqgJCnyVI1XNZdQ7uBtRQ7wisLYSy5p3bcKN45s8z0N5XX37CMtZHg8WMEvbF6Q+BNNPpjuqLZ3n2p0hJ8+nTpo1lq/vOQrVU+DCcsiC38OMawezCmWDdUxbg2PiMkU9F/WZ4MfddfaDwqQ1BBQC0QkUZeRHkOCPndfwQOCKX1IKZ81Ju7MTmN1wqFdHaHxmHICvLvD6er4q4B0o8byjDXO0M79Yt82UMi8E2sqIAzin+FaFk181KNB5Z+5LbvWhORCig==; FCCDCF=[["AKsRol8x0eLcCPRNK87LcFg96i4OohYRu7keT-wXifV77qo_eYe6uZ0ThI1Oxd2-Y4V5wtjFjZW02xgjl0IhpmE9ojyljTmH9lrVeqQI3wXUjtift1w_Dqsor4S-4hEwsOEhBLpQrx8Ijd3oIw7mqxKezHDHZiod4A=="],null,["[[],[],[],[],null,null,true]",1589123041768]]; education-compare-slideout-state=collapsed; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; utag_main=v_id:0171ff1af36300170b586aee949903073006706b009dc$_sn:1$_ss:0$_pn:2%3Bexp-session$_st:1589125090368$ses_id:1589122888547%3Bexp-session$_prevpage:www.usnews.com%2Fbest-colleges%2Fsearch%3Bexp-1589126890272; kw.pv_session=6; sailthru_visitor=9abdf1e6-3e02-427f-9899-6c232865866f; bm_sv=C8E5F93ED4F69A94559E23D6F676C38F~k2zHi/YOvrX2jg2IjDjERaOLYsf7bu+NjQmXeUuPHueXWih3Xm6rjXIC8wg1E225YVqIN2Q3cxjMPj6wlfrOgX8K9b5WW9BLiQIddDKHAGX7gH591ibZ8/bJFn4E/h7PhohIoGJK8PpG6Vel3r3dp//PcCGwzvgJNlUWVUqki3c=; _sp_id.26f9=f626f911-80a4-4912-b0bc-ad1b520357f6.1589122896.2.1589128312.1589124442.54a5f830-9b4f-471e-b326-7e4654bf5bf1; _sp_ses.26f9=*; RT="sl=0&ss=1589123021504&tt=0&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F684d0d40.akstat.io%2F&sh=&dm=usnews.com&si=a65156df-2f6b-4e2a-815d-f7fdf1e8928c`,
    }
};

request(options, function (err, resp, html) {
    debugger
    if (!err) {

        var res= JSON.parse(html);
        //var items=res.data.items
        //var totalItems=res.data.totalItems
        //var totalPages=res.data.totalPages


    }
})
```

Please try this code . [image] maybe you have to put your browser cookie in the request url. since this site api is actually restricted for another applications. in the result